# WP7 Popup shown before thread.sleep but does not appear until after

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, popup

I'm currently using Thread.Sleep(2500) to simulate a network call in a mock layer until we can connect to the web services. I have a created a popup with a progress bar (yes, I am using Jeff Wilcox's progress bar) based on [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx), and have gotten the popup to appear successfully. However, I am running into an issue where the popup doesn't load when I call it after using Thread.Sleep(). The progress bar does not appear until after Thread.Sleep() returns. I'm trying to get this working for an upcoming demo, so I'd like to figure out how to make it work with Thread.Sleep() instead of waiting for the services and hoping it works there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Thread.Sleep` is sleeping the UI thread which is preventing the popup from being displayed until after your method returns. You need can either use the `DispatcherTimer` class to get a call back on the UI thread after some `TimeSpan` has elapsed, or create a new thread which does the sleep.

This is a good lesson for when you do have network operations: don't block the UI thread.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think you can block the UI thread with real services since they are all async in WP7. I understand that Thread.Sleep() blocks the UI thread, but I call my ShowPopup() method before Thread.Sleep(). The idea was that it would show the popup and then block on the UI thread - now that i think about it, even if it worked, the animation wouldn't because it's on the UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not 100% sure, but I think the .Show method (or whatever displays the popup) probably only queues the task of displaying the popup, it probably doesn't actually draw the popup until you relinquish the UI thread.